# Windows add\remove programs repair button won't work after temp folder clean

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-installer

[image: shot]

Hi all. 
I have a problem with windows xp and programs repair. 
Repair won't work from "click here for support information"->Repair after user temp clean.

As you can see on screenshot, windows installer tries to open msi from other user temp folder.
I've checked - C:\windows\installer\ stored cached msi. So if I click "remove" or "change" in programs list - it works correctly. Error caused only by "repair" button in support info dialog.

I've tried to find useful info in google but failed. 
How I can fix this? Also, this issue is reproducible in Windows 7. ( clean temp then press Repair )

Answer (score 2):

In "C:\windows\installer\" the OS only stores a stripped down version of the MSI package, not all its contents. Install files are usually extracted in a temporary location, like the per-machine or per-user temp folder. If the installer is trying to access them when they no longer exist the only solution is to run the original setup package, and trigger the repair from it.

Comment: If it's correct - why chain "change->repair" works?

Comment: I don't understand how do you execute these steps. Where do you have the "Repair" option as a next step for "Change"? From what I can see on my machine Office PIA 2007 shows only the "Remove" button when selected in the list of programs and the "Repair" button in "Support Info" dialog.

Comment: Office PIA 2007 is a example.
In my product i have "change" option.

Chain "Click here for support info"->"Repair" used original msi,
Chain "Change"(if available)->"Repair" used cached msi. 

I don't understand, why.